# I cant translate few words on the website

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, inline-translations

I have magento store 1.9.0 that runs in 3 different languages.

Most of it is translated, but there are few words that i can't translate to any other language from english.

Such as Configurable size attribute, where you must select products' size. IT is translated as a filter but not here in the menu.

> Stock measure. Only x Left.

And a revolution slider static block. apparently it supports only one language. what should i do?

Inline translation does not work, as well as translate.csv, i have also searched all `Mage_xx.csv` files in locale, but still can't translate those words.

Comment: Hi, Ernest. Phrases like "Only x Left" are stored as "Only %s Left" in .csv files - you might try o search such kind of texts to translate them. Also you can enable template path hints and locate exact files where those texts are placed, and check, if they are entered inside of __() function, which is used to translate texts.

Comment: There's also possibility that the string is added via Javascript so you'd have to use JavaScript translate in *.phtml file where it's used to point string in your locale *.csv files.

Comment: @Ernest were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?